# Javascript – PNG not showing when adding dynamically

Tags: javascript

I’m a beginner JS coder and I’m struggling with the following – can anyone please help?

I’m trying to add a series of PNGs to a page using a function which will allow the placement of multiple copies of the same image and also assign a unique reference to each copy of the image.

The images are not showing in the page, plus the console.log() shows that the 2 images created by the code below both have the same position on the page.

```
var imgSrc = 'arrow_red.png';

function generateArrow(numArrows) {

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imgSrc;

    for (i = 1; i <= numArrows; i++) { 
        window['arrow'+i] = img;
    }
}

generateArrow(2);

arrow1.style.position = 'absolute';
arrow1.style.top = '50px';
arrow1.style.left = '50px';

arrow2.style.position = 'absolute';
arrow2.style.top = '100px';
arrow2.style.left = '100px';

console.log(arrow1);
console.log(arrow2);
```

Why are the images not showing in the page and why does the console.log() show that the 2 images created are both using the same positional co-ordinates?

Comment: You are creating the images in memory, but never injecting them into the DOM with something like `parent.appendChild(newChild)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new element, it only exists in memory - - it hasn't been added to the document that the browser is currently rendering. So, it's not enough to create new elements and configure them. You must then inject them into the DOM with [`parentElement.appendChild(newChild)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Here's an example:

```js
let newChild = document.createElement("img");
newChild.src = "https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/D14B1C22-04F8-4FB4-95937D13A0B76545.jpg?w=590&h=393";

let parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
parent.appendChild(newChild); // <-- Now, inject the new element
```

```css
img { width: 400px; }
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Now, in your particular case, you've got more issues than just this to work on. You are only creating a new image element one time because your line that does that is not inside of your loop. Also, the way you are referring to `arrow1` and `arrow2` in your code and with `window['arrow' + i]` indicates that you have `img` elements with `id`s already set up in your HTML, which is not an ideal approach. Next, it's much simpler to set up the CSS you'll want to work with as pre-made classes ahead of time, rather than setting up the CSS as inline styles in the script.

As my answer above indicates, you need to have a parent element that will contain the new element(s) that you create, so your solution would really look something like this:

```js
var imgSrc = 'https://icon2.kisspng.com/20180320/rle/kisspng-arrow-computer-icons-clip-art-red-arrow-line-png-5ab19d059bfa98.5843437015215895096389.jpg';

// You can pick any pre-existing element to be the "parent"
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");

function generateArrow(numArrows) {

  for (i = 1; i <= numArrows; i++) { 
    // The creation of the elementt and it's configuration
    // need to be inside of the loop to make several of them
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.classList.add("position" + i); // Add pre-made CSS classes 
    img.src = imgSrc;
   
    parent.appendChild(img);  // Inject the new element inside of the parent 
  }
}

generateArrow(5);
```

```css
/* 
  Instead of setting inline styles, use pre-made CSS classes
  that you can just connect or disconnect to/from
*/

/* All the injected images get this: */
#parent > img { width:40px; position:absolute; }

/* These get assigned individually */
.position1 { top:50px; left:50px; }
.position2 { top:100px; left:100px; }
.position3 { top:150px; left:150px; }
.position4 { top:200px; left:200px; }
.position5 { top:250px; left:250px; }
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. As a beginner, I’m not sure I fully understand all of it just yet, but I’ll work through it until I do.

Answer (score 0):

You usually add elements to DOM using `document.appendChild(element);`, or in your case: `document.appendChild(img);`. (Or any preferred parent instead of `document`)

---

Edit: removed second part addressing variable declaration, since I didn't notice the `window["arrow" + i] = img`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the generated element to the DOM using the appendChild() method.
Furhermore you're actually just generating a single instance of the image because it's happening once outside of the for-loop. This is why the console shows identical screen positions for 'both' images because actually you're referring to the same image instance.

Try this:

```
function generateArrow(numArrows) {
  var img;
  for (i = 1; i <= numArrows; i++) {
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imgSrc;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    window['arrow' + i] = img;
  }
}
```